# Specify output language of MSVC compiler

Tags: visual-c++

I installed MSVC on windows 7, it works fine, but I encountered a problem.

MSVC compiler chooses language for output (different messages, errors and so on) depending on my system locale. In my case it's Russian, so output encoding is "cp866". Because of this in my IDE, for instance CodeLite, I see output like this:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make -e -f  Makefile
"mingw32-make" ­¥ ï¢«ï¥âáï ¢­ãâà¥­­¥© ¨«¨ ¢­¥è­¥©
ª®¬ ­¤®©, ¨á¯®«­ï¥¬®© ¯à®£à ¬¬®© ¨«¨ ¯ ª¥â­ë¬ ä ©«®¬.
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Anyway, I'd prefer get output in English because it's easier to google.

Is there way to choose output language?

Comment: Consider doing what most of us do: Work on an english windows with english language UI.

Comment: @TomTom, Yeah, I think it's the best way, so just I wonder if I can to change a compiler language in my locale.

Comment: Thoughts: There are some resource DLLs you might be able to delete/replace?  You can set a console code page before running msbuild?